# How to do goto in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a game like family feud where the user gets asked a question and they have to reply 3 times so I was wondering if there was something like `goto` that I could use.

```
Question question = questions.get(new Random().nextInt(questions.size()));
System.out.println(question.getQuestion());
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

//want to put start right here but can't
//start:

String answer = scanner.nextLine();

for (Answer a : question.getAnswers())
{
    if (a.getAnswer().toLowerCase().contains(answer))
    {
        System.out.println(a.getAnswer() + " " + a.getPoints());
        return;
        //Make it go back to start right here
    }
}

System.out.println("WRONG!");
//also make it go back to start right here
```

Comment: Why don't you just run a loop 3 times and exit the loop if there's a wrong answer?

Comment: You're looking for `continue` with labels. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: If the question is "how do I do a goto?", then you're probably doing it wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking this, a `for` loop is all you need:

```
Question question = questions.get(new Random().nextInt(questions.size()));

System.out.println(question.getQuestion());

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String answer = scanner.nextLine();

    boolean correct = false;
    for (Answer a : question.getAnswers()) {
        if (a.getAnswer().toLowerCase().contains(answer)) {
            System.out.println(a.getAnswer() + " " + a.getPoints());
            correct = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!correct) {
        System.out.println("WRONG!");
    }
}
```

`goto` in any language is bad practice, as it makes it difficult to follow the code. There is practically always a better way of accomplishing what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `goto` for that. The better way would be to use `break` and check the result after the loop:

```
Question question = questions.get(new Random().nextInt(questions.size()));
System.out.println(question.getQuestion());
bool success = false;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < 3 && !success; i++) {
    String answer = scanner.nextLine();
    for (Answer a : question.getAnswers()) {
        if (a.getAnswer().toLowerCase().contains(answer)) {
            System.out.println(a.getAnswer() + " " + a.getPoints());
            success = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (!success) {
    System.out.println("WRONG!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try a simple `while` loop around this code like so:

```
String answer = scanner.nextLine();

while (true)
{
    for (Answer a : question.getAnswers())
    {
        if (a.getAnswer().toLowerCase().contains(answer))
        {
            System.out.println(a.getAnswer() + " " + a.getPoints());
        }
        else
            break; // exit the loop if IF statement is false.
    }
    System.out.println("WRONG!");
    break;
}
```